# adsense ошибка в консоле сайта на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense

Хочу зарегистрировать сайт на adsense. Сам cайт на вордпрессе, добавляю код, который дали при регистрации на adsense

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-5504817041156223",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

Захожу на сайт http://stylehouse.kz/ в консоле ошибка http://prntscr.com/i3wb13 . Уже несколько дней вожусь с этой ошибкой не могу понять в чем дело.  Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: У меня нет такой ошибки на вашем сайте. Попробуйте открыть такую ссылку http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js Похоже, у вас какая-то блокировка на уровне вашего компьютера или интернет-провайдера

Comment: скачивается текстовый файл с кодом функции. Проверил также в мозиле, в мозиле показывает следующее http://prntscr.com/i3x3cl . есть идеи что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Отключите блокировщик рекламы (ADBLocker или аналоги) для этого сайта и у вас не будет ошибки. У меня тоже показывает в консоле ошибку

`GET https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT - уже наталкивает на мысль, что нужно проверить блокировщик

Comment: На хроме отлючен, проверил на мозиле и опере еще, там тоже ошибка. На мозиле и опере никаких блокираторов рекламы не стоит, так как я им не пользуюсь и ничего туда не устанавливал.

Comment: хотя странно, а ведь у вас и другая ошибка, судя по скрину, я не обратил внимание на скрин. Но у меня её нет, пользователь KAGG вам тоже писал, что у него нет такой ошибки

Comment: Искали в Google решение по устранению проблемы с `err_name_not_resolved`? Пробовали перезапустить DNS-клиент?

Comment: Не в блокировщике дело. У меня с ним тоже ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT, но без него чисто. А автор пишет о другой ошибке, которую я не вижу у себя.